# Exceptions in http to https redirect in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

I have the following code in my htaccess and it works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.host\.com*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://host.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but I have one derictory, that I shouldn`t be redirected i.e. should be accessed through http, e.g. host.com/nossl/... what should add to my htaccess? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative pattern in `RewriteRule` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.host\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^nossl(/.*)?$ https://host.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```